# Flask-WTF form posts successfully but validation never occurs

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have been struggling around the WTF forms for quite a while now. But this error, never seems to go away. I When ever I try to run this code the form never validates

Views :

```
@bundle.route('/content/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bundle.route('/content/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bundle.route('/content/edit/<posturl>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bundle.route('/content/edit/<posturl>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@fas_login_required
def addcontent(posturl=None):
    form = CreateContent()
    form_action = url_for('content.addcontent')
    if posturl is not None:
        content = Content.query.filter_by(slug=posturl).first_or_404()
        form = CreateContent(obj=content)
        if form.slug.data == posturl and request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            form.populate_obj(content)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('content.addcontent',
                                    posturl=posturl, updated="True"))

    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            query = Content(form.title.data,
                            form.slug.data,
                            form.description.data,
                            form.media_added_ids.data,
                            form.active.data,
                            form.tags.data,
                            g.fas_user['username'],
                            form.type_content.data
                            )
            try:
                db.session.add(query)
                db.session.commit()
                # Duplicate entry
            except Exception as e:
                return str(e)
            return redirect(url_for('content.addcontent',
                                    posturl=form.slug.data, updated="True"))
        else:
            print "Please validate form"
    return render_template('content/edit_content.html', form=form,
                           form_action=form_action, title="Create Content")
```

Form Class :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField
from wtforms import BooleanField, SelectField, validators
from wtforms.validators import Required

__all__ = ['CreateContent']


class CreateContent(Form):
    title = TextField(
        'Title',  [validators.Length(min=4, max=255)])
    slug = TextField(
        'Url-Slug', [validators.Length(min=4, max=255)])
    description = TextAreaField('Content', [validators.Length(min=4)])
    media_added_ids = TextField('media')
    type_content = SelectField(u'Content Type',
                               [Required()],
                               choices=[('blog', 'Blog Post'),
                                        ('media', 'Lecture'),
                                        ('doc', 'Documentation')]
                               )
    # Comma seprated media id's
    active = BooleanField('Published')
    tags = TextField('Tags', [Required()])
    # Comma seprated tag id's
```

And my Template :

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}
        {{ title }}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <div id="Create Content">
        <center><h3> {{ updated }} </h3></center>
        <h2>{{  title  }}</h2>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>
                {{ render_field(form.title) }}
                {{ render_field(form.slug ) }}
                {{ render_field(form.description ) }}
                {{ render_field(form.media_added_ids)}}
                {{ render_field(form.type_content) }}
                {{ render_field(form.active) }}
                {{ render_field(form.tags )}}
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Any help will be highly apprieciated

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error?

Comment: let me explain you in detail. When I leave  feild blank in the form . it notifies me of validation errors, but when I fill all the values in the form. And then submit the form .. even then the form.validate() returns false. And data never goes into databse

Comment: Add this to your code to see why the form is not validating: print form.errors()

Comment: http://fpaste.org/105130/06843140/
This prints nothing.

Comment: Hammad, can you provide a simple script (http://www.sscce.org/) that illustrates your problem.  I don't think we can cut and paste your code above to recreate the problem.  Without being able to recreate it, we're simply making random guesses.  The easier it is to recreate your problem, the more likely you are to attract people willing to help fix it.

Comment: `even then the form.validate() returns false` I smell a red herring. You have a lot going on in this method specifically a lot of `try/except` blocks and conditionals. I wouldn't be suprised if you are throwing a rogue `Error` due to data being malformed for its intended column definition or `posturl` unintentionally be `None`. Can you isolate this problem to just WTForms? Can you print the content of the request on a failing `POST`? As is its not answerable.

Comment: This is the production code, github.com/echevemaster/fedora-college

Anywys I was able to fix it.. :) THanks for your help. There was a small error I was missing {{form.hidden_tag()}} . I have created a pull request on the project. Thank you all.

Comment: @HammadHaleem can you provide some more **post-mortem** debug info. Specifically what error messages you were seeing. This will help folks in the future who have a similar problem retrace your steps.

Comment: Well actually, the form.errors never returned any errors. I guess, it should not. Because all present feilds Were being validated correctly. The problem was that the flask was expecting CSFR id, to complete the form. Which once added resolved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the CSFR tokens are activated in a flask application setting, a CSFR token is included in each form. If developer has activated the setting and not included it in the form template the flask WTF would automatically reject the request.

The solution to this problem was to the following tag :

```
{{form.hidden_tag()}}
```

Once added, a CSFR id is included in the request and sent to the views for validation by the WTForms.

If you haven't included this token no errors will appear in the `form.errors` dictionary. If you iterate over this dictonary no errors will be show, but the form.validate method will return false.

Answer (score 5):

Flask-WTF adds the `CSRF` token automatically if it is activated in your `Flask` settings. If this  setting is active and it isn't included in the form submission the submission will be rejected. The solution in this case is to add the `hidden_tag` field in the template so that it is included in the form submission.

```
{{form.hidden_tag()}}
```